# Should rest resource have same structure in collection

Tags: rest, restful-architecture, api-design, laminas-api-tools

I found question about subset of REST when display resource by `GET /task/ID` and as row in collection `GET /task`.
[REST - Resource and Collection Representations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17408770/rest-resource-and-collection-representations)

I'm using Apigility.

I know REST is not official, but want to hold as strict as could with overall best practice/standard.

Can i have others fields in collection and resource. Of cource part will be the same, but for collection i need some extra information for filtering and in resource there is now need for them.

Is this will breaking in any way some rules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not uncommon to return partial representations of resources in a REST collection response, while the full representation is returned when the singleton endpoint is requested.

Read for example [here](http://51elliot.blogspot.se/2014/06/rest-api-best-practices-4-collections.html) (one of the first links I found with [this search on Google](https://www.google.se/search?q=partial%20resource%20rest%20collection), there are many more).

> **Getting a collection**
>
> Getting a collection, like "members" may return 
>    1) the entire list of resources as a list of links, 
>    2) partial representations of each resource, or  
>    3) full representations of all the resources in the collection.

So it is not uncommon that a resource representation in a collection differs from the singleton representation, but I would say you would rather have less then more data.

What particular fields were you thinking about adding to the response in your collection? Can you give an example?

Answer (score 0):

That would certainly be unusual, it's better to be consistent, why have 2 models for the same thing? Looking at the [Richardson Maturity Model level 1](http://martinfowler.com/articles/richardsonMaturityModel.html#level1), one would expect a service endpoint mapped to a (single) resource. And what do you mean by extra information for filtering?

If that's a frequent scenario, you might want to handle it on the server through templated URIs (query string) like so:

`GET /task?type={type}&property2={value2}`

Otherwise, you could just fetch them all and do the filtering on the client (in which case you'll surely need those properties).

Comment: And what you think about create subset of columns, like in post I gave in description?